# Question on Silverlight's Unit of Measurements

Tags: silverlight, dpi, units-of-measurement

I want to build a small Silverlight application that will save a Canvas (and it's child objects) as a high-resolution JPG or PNG.

I'm not understanding how to work with the units in silverlight since they're based on pixels. How would I go about specifying the size of the Canvas object in pixels if my goal is to save it as a JPG or PNG with the exact measurements of 5" x 7" ???

In other words, how can we specify measurement values in Silverlight that will print out in exact inches since different monitors have different DPI values.

Thanks!!

Comment: I think you should consider two different situation you are dealing with. Showing image on screen in 5" x 7" is going to be hard and most likely unnecessary. What you want is to save image in a way that then it is printed or otherwise consumed it shows properly. That is you need to decide on target output device and set DPI of your saved image accordingly. 300 is common dpi for printing. Pixel size will be 5*DPI x 7*DPI.

Answer (score 0):

Silverlight printing measurement implement 96 dpi means one inch represent 96 pixels.
you can use the Measure function of the Framework element to get the DesiredSize.

You can get more info [enter link description @
 http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.uielement.measure%28v=vs.95%29.aspx

Answer (score 0):

Theoretically a Canvas of Width 480 and Height 672 ought to be 5" x 7" on screen.  This is heavily dependant on the Video Card / Monitor devices reporting windows an accurate DPI

However in reality what will happen is that on a bigger monitor (where the resolution has not increased proportionally) the content just looks bigger.

Trying to get exact sizes is actually quite difficult.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the answers   :)

Here's a link that describes very well what I needed to know:

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/43520/Device-Independent-Units-to-Points-to-Inches